# C object macros expanding to a C function macro

Tags: c, macros, header-files

I have a C file containing

```
#define A f
#define B (
#define C x
#define D )

#define f(x) 1

int main () {
  A B C D;
  return 0;
}
```

And when I run the preprocessor, I get

```
int main () {
  f ( x );
}
```

and the last macro doesn't get expanded.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The preprocessor runs only *once*. Once it has run, and expanded the `A` through `D` macros, there's no more macro expansion.

Comment: I tested this and it's weird because if I have 

"#define A B
#define B C"

then the preprocessor produces "C"

Comment: That's because the expansion of a *single* macro will be recursively expanded. Your `A` through `D` macros just expand to a series of tokens, there's no further macros to be expanded.

Comment: After the preprocessor expands a macro, it rescans from the beginning of that macro's replacement text.  But once it gets beyond that point, it does not backtrack.

Comment: Is this only a theoretical question or for learning purposes? If you have a (possibly more complicated) real use case, explain what you want to achieve and add more details about your use case.

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?*  Expecting sanity from the C preprocessor.  That way madness lies.  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you pass the macros as arguments to another macro, that would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A f
#define B (
#define C x
#define D )
#define x 1
#define f(x) x

#define EXPAND(a,b,c,d) a b c d

int main () {
  printf("%d", EXPAND(A,B,C,D) );
  return 0;
}
```

Here the "macro replacement list" inside the `EXPAND` macro is rescanned after each token gets expanded, until there are no more macros left to expand. Whereas in your example each macro just gets replaced with the corresponding contents of the `#define`.

Comment: You could also define `EXPAND` with a single argument, `#define EXPAND(x) x`, and call it with a single argument `A B C D`, i.e. `printf("%d", EXPAND(A B C D) );`.